# undetermined behavior while printing elements in array of character pointer?

Tags: c, string, char, strtok

i am trying to parse input to separate it into commands and arguments,
I am able to split but problem is occurring when i try to assign into my array that contains a number of strings.
for ex:

```
cmd1<infile |cmd2 -a -b -c|cmd3 -x -y -z>outfile
```

into commands with argument ,splitting is ok but finally when i print my array its not showing correct output , i am unable to understand working of char* in c .

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<malloc.h>

char* Getfile(char *input,int flag)
{
int i,k;
char *file;
//printf("\n++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
//puts(input);
if(strcmp("exit",input)==0)
exit(0);

 for(i=0;input[i]!='\0';i++)
 {
  if(flag==0 && input[i]=='<')
  break;
  else if(flag==1 && input[i]=='>'  )
  {
   if(input[i-1]!='2')
   break;
   else if(input[i-1]=='2' && input[i-2]!=' ' )
   break;
  }
  else if(flag==2 && input[i]=='>' && input[i-1]=='2' && input[i-2]==' ' )
  break;
 }//for

 if(input[i]==NULL)
 return NULL;

 i++;

 //cmd f1  2>f2
 for(k=0;input[i]!='>' && input[i]!='<'&& input[i]!=NULL ;i++,k++)//dont include ' ' cond otherwise cmd< f1 will not work
 {
   if(input[i]==' ' && input[i+1]=='2' && input[i+2]=='>')
   break;

   file[k]=input[i];
  // printf("\n %d %c",i,input[i]); //  getch();
  }
 file[k]=NULL;

//  printf("\n return file%d is \n",flag);
//  puts(file);
  //getch();
  return file;
}//function
//--------------------------------------------------------
char *Getcommand(char *input)
{
char *cmd;
int i,k;
for(k=0,i=0;input[i]!='>' && input[i]!='<'&& input[i]!=NULL;i++,k++)
 {
   cmd[k]=input[i];
   //printf(" %c",cmd[k]);
 }//for
 if(input[i]=='>' && input[i-1]=='2' &&input[i-2]==' ' )
 cmd[k-2]=NULL;
 cmd[k]=NULL;

 //printf("\ncommand is");
// puts(cmd);
// getch();;
 return cmd;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------


void main()
{
/*
char *args[10][20]={
{"ls","-a","-i",(char*)NULL},
{"sort",(char*)NULL},
{"wc","-c",(char*)NULL}
}; */

char *args[10][20],*input,*commands[10],*temp[10];
int i=0,k=0,noc=-1;
char *inputcopy,*inputcopy2,*inputfile,*outputfile,*errorfile[10];
clrscr();
//------------
printf("enter string\n");
gets(input);
strcpy(inputcopy,input);
commands[0]=strtok(inputcopy,"|");

for(i=0;commands[i]!=NULL;)
{ commands[++i]=strtok(NULL,"|");
}
noc=i-1; //no of commands brgin from 0

strcpy(inputfile,Getfile(commands[0],0));
strcpy(outputfile,Getfile(commands[noc],1));

i=0;
while(i<=noc)
{
 strcpy(inputcopy,Getcommand(commands[i]));
  k=0;
  //----
 args[i][k]=strtok(inputcopy," ");
 while(args[i][k]!=NULL)
 args[i][++k]=strtok(NULL," ");
 //------- immediate printing show args[i][k] has correct value :/ -----------
 for(k=0;args[i][k]!=NULL;k++)
 printf("\n --args[%d][%d]=  %s ",i,k,args[i][k]);
// getch();
 //-----
i++;
}
//---------
printf("\n outputfile=%s",outputfile);
printf("\n inputfile=%s",inputfile);
//===========but here actual printing is not showing correct output=====
i=0;
while(i<=noc)
{
 printf("\n**********comands no %d *******",i);
 for(k=0;args[i][k]!=NULL;k++)
 printf("\n args[%d][%d] %s ",i,k,args[i][k]);

 getch();
 i++;
}

//------
getch();

}//main
```

Comment: Please pipe your code through `indent`, add empty lines where appropriate, and remove harmful comments like `//for` - they serve no purpose other than readability.

Comment: i am not getting your point .

Comment: @userXXX I meant: "format your code because it's an unreadable mess."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared char *File but you didn't allocate any space for it. You are trying to copy contents into an array that is just pointing to some space in memory and then expanding it, undefined behaviour I believe. Use malloc/calloc to create space for it.

```
    file = (char * ) malloc(sizeof(char) * maxLength);
```

Where you define the maxLength of the array and then in your for loop copy the contents in.

```
   for(k=0;input[i]!='>' && input[i]!='<'&& input[i]!=NULL && k < maxLength ;i++,k++)//dont include ' ' cond otherwise cmd< f1 will not work
   {
       if(input[i]==' ' && input[i+1]=='2' && input[i+2]=='>')
       break;

       file[k]=input[i];
       // printf("\n %d %c",i,input[i]); //  getch();
   }
```

Comment: how to allocate space for char*args[10][20] so that it will work properly ?

Comment: If the size can be determined at compile time then just use a char array.. char myvar[][] otherwise you need a pointer to a pointer. Where the space allocated is the amount of arrays, each of which also need to have space allocated.